# Why do some armadillos roll into a ball while others don't?

Tags: evolution, zoology

My question is pretty simple that why do some species of armadillos (like [three-banded](http://www.arkive.org/southern-three-banded-armadillo/tolypeutes-matacus/)) roll into a ball, while others don't?

Comment: [Para 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo#Habitat_and_anatomy)

Comment: @Tytoalba Thanks! and Yes I know that, perhaps I haven't been able to word my question properly. I am more interested to know about why they were evolved this way (to have less plates, etc.)